# Which Debian architecture, armel or armhf, do I use to emulate a BeagleBoneBlack?

Tags: linux, debian, beagleboneblack

I need to create a virtual machine that emulates the BeagleBoneBlack for development purposes.

I would like to create a virtual machine using Oracle VirtualBox, but I am not sure which version of Wheezy I need to download. On [Debian's Site](https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/), they list three ARM architectures:

- arm64
- armel
- armhf

Since the BeagleBoneBlack's [processor is 32 bit](http://www.ti.com/product/am3358), I am assuming that it is not the arm64 version. But I cannot figure out if it is the armel or armhf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **armel** architecture supports the ARMv4 instruction set.
This architecture handles floating-point computation in a compatibility mode which it slows performance but allows compatibility with code written for processors without floating point units.
So you can use the armel architecture to build high compatible systems.

The **armhf** architecture supports ARMv7 platform, and more, it adds direct hardware floating-point support.
This means the armhf architecture is faster than the armel one, but it lacks the compatibility with the old architectures.

Source: http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2013/01/31/armhf-versus-armel/

Comment: So, it looks like armel is the best way to go?

Comment: I would take armhf, when i am running sudo apt-get update and upgrade it loads also armhf sources.